# Few questions on dvd ram/rom

Tags: dvd

- Why  other dvd rom/ram can read data from scratched disk and others cannot. For me its a comparison between LG and Lite On. Lite on, gets errors while reading disk with scratches. LG can read disk with scratches with no problems. Why is that?
- Is it possible to modify the software or the driver of the dvd rom so that it won't get errors when copying data from disk with scratches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The quality of laser in the product can increase readability. Because Lite on is more of a value brand Vs. LG, the laser is most likely a lower quality. Thus, the lite-on struggles, while the LG has less problems.
2. As mentioned above, it is the laser within the device that determines how well the DVD can be read. The problems you are having are not driver related.